# why remote button_to is not working for me?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

**remote botton_to is not working**

In the index page, i have code

```
        <%= button_to "Edit User Info", 
                      :method => :edit_user_info,
                      :remote => true  
        %>
```

in the controller, i am testing it for printing a log message, but it didnt work for me

```
def edit_user_info
    logger.debug "===========================2"
    redirect_to my_account_path
end
```

so, how can i fix it...thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:method` attribute takes a symbol of a HTTP verb such as `get`, `post`, `put` or `delete`, not a controller action. If you want to call a specific action within a controller, you could use the `:action` attribute (and possibly the `:controller` attribute as well).